# How do I rotate MPMoviePlayer as the movie is playing in iOS 8 with Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'd like to ask and answer my own question, in case others will find it helpful.

The moviePlayer would begin to play nicely as expected using

```
moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds
```

But, when rotated mid-movie, the tabBar would rotate, but not the moviePlayer. This would crop a portion of the movie screen, or it wouldn't change to fill the whole screen as originally expected.

[image: Changing rotation of portrait to landscape crops the mpmovieplayer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the func viewDidLoad() add this notification service:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter() .addObserver(self, selector: "movieOrientationChanged", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

and, here's the method (moviePlayer is a class variable of type MPMoviePlayerController) that responds to that notification:

```
func movieOrientationChanged() {
     moviePlayer!.view.frame = self.view.bounds 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for swift 4  add this code in viewDidLoad

> ```
> NotificationCenter.default .addObserver(self, selector: #selector(VideoViewViewController.movieOrientationChanged), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
> ```